# Manipulate text-shadow color with HTML5 color input type

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am attempting to change the color of a text shadow using the HTML5 color input type:

```
<script>
$('#shadowcolor').on('change', function() {
    var shadowcolor = $('#shadowcolor').val();
    $('#output').css('text-shadow', '5px 5px shadowcolor');
});
</script>

<label class="color" for="shadowcolor">Color</label><input id="shadowcolor" type="color" value="#ff0000" />

<div id="output">
    <h1>Some Text with a Shadow</h1>
</div>
```

I don't think I am setting the "shadowcolor" variable correctly however, as this just breaks the shadow. Does anyone know how I could implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, here, is that you tried to set the color to actually be the string `"shadowcolor"` as opposed to the value of the variable. To fix this, you will want to append the value of `shadowcolor` (the variable) onto the string `"5px 5px "`.

Try this:

```
 $('#output').css('text-shadow', '5px 5px ' + shadowcolor);
```

Comment: No worries - It's what we're here for :)

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/Hm9ZK/**

```
$('#shadowcolor').on('change', function() {
var shadowcolor = $('#shadowcolor').val();
$('#output').css('text-shadow', '5px 5px' + shadowcolor);
});
```

Comment: I removed my comment out of consideration - what you may not have seen is the part where I pointed out that while it works like that in some browsers, it will fail in others.

Comment: Anyways I will remove my answer since as you said it is not working in some browsers.

Comment: Keep it - the fiddle is valid +1